# Showing prefix of token in error message?

Tags: access-token

In our development context we have a lot of different tokens. If a developer gets "permission denied", it is often not immediately clear which token was used.

I would like to improve the error message and show a prefix of the token.

Imagine I have a token like this:

```
aragq29uFDgfDdgf44SdfgfSSgfdRsgdDG45
```

I would like to show:

```
permission denied (token starts with "aragq...")
```

Is this a security risk?

Comment: Is the token purely random like a password, or does it have some kind of encoding of other data?

Answer (score 21):

Revealing part of an authentication token reduces the overall security of that token, because an attacker who can get hold of the first part doesn't have to guess or brute-force the entire token any more. But given the length of your token (36 mixed-alpha-numeric characters) that's probably not a huge concern, because by revealing five characters you're dropping the effective strength from ~214 bits to ~184 bits, which is probably still more than sufficient for your purposes.

You probably don't need to show that many characters though. Even just two characters (3844 possible combinations) is likely to be enough unless your users have *a lot* of different keys.

---

But a better solution would be to store some kind of identifier or description along with the key, and then you can display that to the user in the error message. So rather than "*The key starting a5*", it would be "*The key named: Dave's test key*"

Comment: While the bruteforce weakness that gets introduced *could* be considered too small to worry about, labelling is the far better way to go on so many levels.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph: it's not hard (for API users) to lose track of the relationship between tokens and their identifiers/descriptions/labels, especially if they have several different tokens to deal with but not enough to justify a formal secret storage system. (I am asserting this from personal experience :-p) So I'd suggest that, in the interest of finding an appropriate balance between security and usability, showing something intrinsic to the token itself is still valuable. This could be done along with a label.

Comment: @DavidZ An easy fix for that is to bake the label directly into the token, producing something like "DaveTest_aragq29u…". The whole thing can be treated as a single opaque bit string for authentication (so no API changes are needed) while also using the first part in error messages, logs, etc.

Comment: @TooTea Indeed, good idea. I actually had an answer written up suggesting something along those lines before I realized it wouldn't be worth a separate post, though I like your idea better. I suppose it would be best to restrict the label to a short string with a limited character set (or "slugify" and truncate the label before embedding it in the token).